# How to send and receive data in a persistent connection with Dart?

Tags: java, flutter, dart, http, sockets

I am trying to have my client(s) connect their Dart (Flutter) running devices to my server running a Java ServerSocket. The connection establishes properly and all headers are received by the server, however no other data is received.
The configuration issue must be with the dart code below, since my other Java client to Java server with the same code works.

Dart client code:

```
// if the WebSocketChannel is not closed, close it
try {
  channel?.sink.close();
} catch (e) {
  // do nothing
}

channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse(globals.serverUrl));

channel?.sink.add("Test notification");
```

Java server code:

```
outStream = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

while (true) {
    String input = inStream.readLine();
    if (input == null) {
        socket.close();
        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();
        System.out.println("Client disconnected");
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Received: " + input);
}
```

Server output:

```
Received: GET / HTTP/1.1
Received: user-agent: Dart/2.17 (dart:io)
Received: connection: Upgrade
Received: cache-control: no-cache
Received: accept-encoding: gzip
Received: sec-websocket-version: 13
Received: host: localhost:8080
Received: sec-websocket-extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Received: sec-websocket-key: lys/+BV+IIH5Mm52V0jUmw==
Received: upgrade: websocket
Received:
```

Note that the client does not disconnect, so the connection is indeed persistent.
The weird behaviour is with sending and receiving custom data:

Client to Server:

results in no data being sent or error showing

Server to Client:

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException: HttpException: Invalid response line, uri = http://localhost:8080/

The message transmitted from Server to Client here was just "test" and the client was listening with:

```
String? response = await channel?.stream.first;
```

The response would remain unused and was listened for after the completion of the sent message as seen in the Dart code sample.

Comment: Do you know what a websocket is? It's an extra protocol you can use on a socket to make a socket connection look enough like HTTP that a web browser and web server can use it. If you don't know what a websocket is, and you don't have a web browser or web server involved, then you're probably using one by accident.

Comment: Thank you very much, it appears that I have accidentally used a WebSocket. Using the normal Socket worked like a charm.

Comment: Please don't add things like "solved" to the title or add the solution to the question. If you managed to solve the problem, either accept the answer that helped you solve it. If there is only a comment (like here), ask the commenter to post an answer, or post your own answer.